# How do I restore the previous "Command-Space" search?

Tags: spotlight

When I use "Command-Space" on my Mac I want it to search only my files, not the Internet or the galaxy at large. Yesterday when I tried to use it I was presented with an infinite variety of options, which I do not want!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To limit what Spotlight shows

Open System Preference > Spotlight

Disable Spotlight Suggestions..or anything you do not want to see.

[image]

Comment: You don't know what OS the user is using

Comment: @DManokhin the Spotlight option for `suggestions` has been ther for last few OS X versions.

Comment: I'm using High Sierra.

Comment: I am to, so why is my answer not working for you